# Is it possible to finish the Domain of Anguish quests with heroes?

Tags: guild-wars

Is it possible to finish the Domain of Anguish quests with heroes? What are the tactics/builds?

Comment: with just heroes, doubtful, but with heroes as supplement definitely

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is (or was) doable, and actually someone posted a screenshot on Guilgwarsguru forums right within a exzessive discussion on beating Domain of Anguish (DoA) and Fissure of Woe (FoW) alone only with heros.
[image]
[See this guildwarsguru Thread.](http://www.guildwarsguru.com/forum/doa-and-fow-with-heroes-t10472576.html)

But I would advice to not attempt this unless you are REALLY experienced, it requires HUGE amounts of skill, in my opinion.

Someone also posted his [complete build](http://www.gwpvx.com/User:Illoyon/Team_-_7_Hero_DoA) on pvxwiki. It says this should be foolproof but I have no personal experience with it.

Comment: FYI I did Fissure of Woe (FoW) alone only with heros. It is really easy. I used the gwpvx 7 Hero Player Support Build (http://www.gwpvx.com/Build:Team_-_7_Hero_Player_Support).

Comment: I think DoA is a whole different level, I used to do both in SC guilds back when I played ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is in fact, feasible to do a hero run of the DoA.

HOWEVER! Doing so requires luck, skill, and a really precise setup, perfectly tailored to all areas. (The mission itself is much harder. However, going solo can allow you to cheat at the end a little, but it requires frame-perfect timing to keep the gate open.) (Fun Fact: In Hard Mode, Mallyx the Unyielding is actually one level higher than his own god. Or any god you fight. At level 33, though, he isn't the highest-leveled creature in the game.)

As for the Fissure of Woe, that's a lot harder, since you can't cycle out parties. Hope you can micromanage seven people, because you are going to need it.

The Underworld, on the other hand, is a whole 'nuther kettle o' fish. Since the Skeletons of Dhuum started to appear, it's gotten progressively more hostile.
And ever since November 2009, well... let's just say if you're gunning for the forgotten god of death, bring no more than two heroes/henchmen if you can actually get people to join you and go all-ranged (pet meatshields acceptable.) Otherwise... Well, let's just say that you should have absolutely perfect timing with Scrolls of Resurrection, be part Dervish to take advantage of the trump card known as Eternal Aura (or part Monk with perfect timing on Unyielding Aura,) and have many Cornerstones of Power on hand.
Oh, and be on South Korea's Air Force StarCraft team.

In other words: Go all out with the consumables. Use everything you have to defeat the impossible challenges. And don't feel afraid to flee or to catch your breath.